# Xpath - select element with only closing tag

Tags: html, xpath

I am new to xpath and have been stuck on this for way too long.  Is it possible to get to the upc value of 0305064523219 from the example below?

I was trying `//div[@class='prdct3']/strong[4]` but of course that only includes 'UPC:' in between the strong tags.  I need to go out to the `<br />` tag.  is there a way to have xpath get the element after an element?

```
<div class="prdct3">
<p><strong>Description:</strong></p>

<p><a href="/catalog/?JOJ4026UP=jojoblister-card-2-
colors-asstd">Digital Watch on Blister Card 2 Colors Asstd.</a></p>
<strong>Item Size:</strong> 6.75" x 3.5" x .75"<br />
<strong>Case:</strong> 144 <strong>Inner:</strong> 24<br />
<strong>UPC:</strong> 0305064523219<br />
<strong>WT:</strong> 10 <strong>CF:</strong> 1.82<br />
<strong>Sub-Category:</strong> AC06<br />
<strong>Origin:</strong> China<br /><div class="floatRight"><a 
class='iframe' href="/_forms/?JOJ4032P"><img 
 src="/_images/btn_questions.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```js
function xpath(selector, root) {
    return document.evaluate(selector, root || document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

var node = xpath('//div[@class="prdct3"]/strong[text()="UPC:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]');
console.log(node.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="prdct3">
<p><strong>Description:</strong></p>

<p><a href="/catalog/?JOJ4026UP=jojoblister-card-2-
colors-asstd">Digital Watch on Blister Card 2 Colors Asstd.</a></p>
<strong>Item Size:</strong> 6.75" x 3.5" x .75"<br />
<strong>Case:</strong> 144 <strong>Inner:</strong> 24<br />
<strong>UPC:</strong> 0305064523219<br />
<strong>WT:</strong> 10 <strong>CF:</strong> 1.82<br />
<strong>Sub-Category:</strong> AC06<br />
<strong>Origin:</strong> China<br /><div class="floatRight"><a 
class='iframe' href="/_forms/?JOJ4032P"><img 
 src="/_images/btn_questions.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

We find the `strong` tag whose text is `UPC:`, then take the first following sibling text node.

`following-sibling::` is an [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#axes).